# Include a HTML template for one page in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a dull About-me Page. I would like it to be more responsive and want it to be like a CV- template. So I saw [PerfectCV](http://themeforest.net/item/perfectcv-responsive-cv-resume-theme/5230603) and [CeeVee](http://www.styleshout.com/templates/preview/Ceevee10/#resume). I would like to incorporate it into my website for just my about-me page.

The question is how to incorporate it. Need some guidance on going about doing it..

Answer (score 0):

Just prepare a file in your theme folder xyz.php, then just make it a template of wordpress and provide it a template name. Put your css in style.css file and just include this template to About-me page through admin panel. All the code you have put in your template will only work for About-me page.

Answer (score -1):

simple go to your admin panel. Click pages. create a page and put your html content with inline css. Thats all. You can change settings to make this page as home page too. If you need more help please let me know.

Comment: I meant if you want to add css in your html page use inline styles.

Comment: I can help this much only. If you want more, yOu can hire me for this work as freelancer. Thank you :)